# The cart item number gets over shadowed after being logged in

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, lms

I customized wplms nav menu, now the cart item number inside  gets overshadowed after logging in

here's what the cart looks like:
https://prnt.sc/uRFyFlSm5_vx (when logged in)

here's what it looks like:

https://prnt.sc/fl5n6ZccipJL (when logged out)

I tried overring the css but had no luck.

```
header.sleek.transparent.fix .vbpcart span em {
    background: #FFE074 !important;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    font-style: normal;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    color: #000 !important;
    padding: 5px;
    left: 9px;
}
```

here's the css

Comment: Very little information, give example to reproduce your question point

Comment: I am guessing, some kind of `overflow: hidden` is destroying the UI.

Comment: @VijayHardaha , I made the **overflow: inherit;** in the main span and it worked! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how on the working page you are able to scroll, while the faulty page is fixed.

```css
.sleek .topmenu>li:first-child a>span {
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

Using the `overflow` property, you can restore this scroll.

Comment: Hey! I made an edit (awaiting approval), try and be descriptive in your solution. It's great to provide an answer, but unless the creator of the question understands why this works - they will have the same problem in the future. Just a few sentences works fine (: